# How can I convert a 120V chandelier to 240V?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I have a chandelier made for the USA market and runs on 110-120 volts. What modifications do I need to make it work in India which has 220-240 volts? Will it need to be rewired?

Answer (score 2):

The wire is usually rated for 600V; check that first if it is and you can find lamps that fit the sockets at 220-240V with the same wattage or less than the maximum wattage. If lamps that fit at the correct wattage are available you could connect the black wire center pin on the fixture to your hot and the white wire to the neutral conductor or shell and last if a metal fixture connect the ground from the fixture to the service ground and it should work. There are sockets to switch from U.S. base to European bases so that bulbs from overseas can fit.

Comment: am I missing something here or is not this the way that it would be wired from the factory here in the States?

Comment: I'm also confused. What, if any, changes are expected to be needed assuming that the wire is adequate?

Comment: A 120-V lamp fixture has to have heavier wires than a 240-V fixture for the same wattage bulb. If you have 240-V lamps that fit the base, then just use it as is.

Comment: I agree Jim, I was just concerned about the voltage since some U.S. fixtures may not use 600v wiring but most do.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it need to be rewired?

No, it does not need to be re-wired. Just buy lamps rated for the voltage that you are using. They should be readily available in India.

Wire it properly as Ed Beal points out and you will be good to go.

Good luck!